# Writing a function to compute the left spine of a tree

Tags: haskell

I'm needing some help in figuring out how to create a `leftSpine` function in Haskell.
Basically, it is supposed to take all the left most leafs and put them into a list, but whenever I run my code I get an empty list. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
data Tree x = Leaf | Node (Tree x) x (Tree x)
    deriving Show

leftSpine :: Tree x -> [x]
leftSpine Leaf  = []
leftSpine (Node lt x rt) = (leftSpine lt)
```

And here is my code to test it.

```
leftSpine (Node (Node (Node Leaf 1 Leaf) 2 (Node Leaf 3 Leaf))
                4
                (Node (Node Leaf 5 Leaf) 6 (Node Leaf 7 Leaf)))
```

It should equal `[4,2,1]` but it just comes up as `[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
leftSpine :: Tree x -> [x]
leftSpine   Leaf  = []
leftSpine   (Node lt x rt) =  x:leftSpine lt
```

You weren't actually putting anything into the list.  The difference is the `x:leftSpine lt` instead of `leftSpine lt`.

Comment: I can't believe that I could not see that!! I made the change, ran the code and it works perfectly. Thanks alot!

Comment: It happens to us all.  No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Your code plainly says that the result is always the empty list.

The first case says that the left spine of a leaf is the empty list. Ok so far.

The second case says that the left spine of a node is exactly the left spine of the node's left child.

So if we want to find the left spine of a tree, we'll just keep chasing down the left children of the nodes we reach, knowing that the answer is exactly equal to the left spine of the next left child. Either we eventually find a leaf, and our result is the empty list, or the tree is infinite and we never return a result at all. There is nothing in your code that could ever return anything else.

---

The key to writing a recursive function of this kind is to figure out what the answer is for the base case (`Leaf`, here), and then for the non-base cases (`Node`, here) you need to figure out how to combine the sub-solutions with the local information here to generate a full solution.

In this case the left spine of a `Leaf` is easy, as there's no data at all. So then how would you combine the information from `Node lt x rt` with `leftSpine lt` to get the left spine of the whole tree?